# How can I ping a list of domain names and returning the IP address along with each domain?

Tags: command-line, ip, ping, domain-name

I have a list of domains I want to ping, and I want to return the domain name and the IP address it resolves to in a similar fashion to how `ping` returns for one domain:

```
PING domaina.com (1.1.1.1): 56 data bytes
PING domainb.com (2.2.2.2): 56 data bytes
```

I've tried using `fping` with a combination of flags such as `-A` and `-d`, but I only seem to be able to get either the IP or the domain name, which is useless to me.

How can I ping a whole list of domain names in one go and get both the domain name and IP address together for each domain?

Comment: is using dig a option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using dig is an option you can create a list of domains (one per line) you want to query and use the following script.

```
#!/bin/bash

domainlist=$1

while read domain; do
  ipaddress=`dig $domain +short`
  echo "Domain:  $domain"
  echo "IP Address:  $ipaddress"
done < "$domainlist"
```

syntax for use should be `./name_of_script.sh file_containing_the_domain_list`

Comment: thanks - however when I run this I get no output. I have a script.sh file with the contents you gave me, and a domains.txt with all of the domains each separated by a space, and I'm doing `./script.sh ./domains.txt`

Comment: Just realised I'm an idiot and I need to put each domain on a new line! Thanks, seems to work fine now!